# Pandas: how to prevent df.append() from returning NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append the content of one dataframe into another. Here is basic example of what I am working with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['001','001','001','002','002','002','004','004'],
                    'Date':['2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-02','2020-01-03'],
                    'Quantity': [100,100,100,50,50,50,60,60],
                    'fx' :[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1],
                    'fy' : [1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['001','001','001','002','002','002', '003'],
                    'Date':['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03','2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03','2019-02-02'],
                    'Quantity': [100,100,100,50,50,50,20]})
```

Now I want to append the content of df2 into df1, but the issue is that it results in some NaN here and there in df1

```
histo = df1.append(df2)
histo = histo.sort_values('Id')
print(histo)

    Id        Date  Quantity   fx   fy
0  001  2020-01-01       100  1.0  1.0
1  001  2020-01-02       100  1.0  1.0
2  001  2020-01-03       100  1.0  1.0
0  001  2019-01-01       100  NaN  NaN
1  001  2019-01-02       100  NaN  NaN
2  001  2019-01-03       100  NaN  NaN
3  002  2020-01-01        50  2.0  3.0
4  002  2020-01-02        50  2.0  3.0
5  002  2020-01-03        50  2.0  3.0
3  002  2019-01-01        50  NaN  NaN
4  002  2019-01-02        50  NaN  NaN
5  002  2019-01-03        50  NaN  NaN
6  003  2019-02-02        20  NaN  NaN
6  004  2020-01-02        60  1.0  1.0
7  004  2020-01-03        60  1.0  1.0
```

the output that I want to achieve is that for each 'Id' row, the values of fx and fy continue being the same. the result would look like this:

```
    Id        Date  Quantity   fx   fy
0  001  2020-01-01       100  1.0  1.0
1  001  2020-01-02       100  1.0  1.0
2  001  2020-01-03       100  1.0  1.0
0  001  2019-01-01       100  1.0  1.0
1  001  2019-01-02       100  1.0  1.0
2  001  2019-01-03       100  1.0  1.0
3  002  2020-01-01        50  2.0  3.0
4  002  2020-01-02        50  2.0  3.0
5  002  2020-01-03        50  2.0  3.0
3  002  2019-01-01        50  2.0  3.0
4  002  2019-01-02        50  2.0  3.0
5  002  2019-01-03        50  2.0  3.0
6  003  2019-02-02        20  2.0  3.0
6  004  2020-01-02        60  1.0  1.0
7  004  2020-01-03        60  1.0  1.0
```

what can I do to achieve the above output? I cannot find it in pandas documentation. Thanks

Comment: Add .ffill maybe? `histo = histo.sort_values('Id').ffill()`

Comment: that's it! Thank you I could not remember it! and why this is not in the documentation, and I feel like it would be useful to have it as a parameter inside of the append fonction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ffill, forward fills NaN value with the last non-NaN value seen in a column.

```
histo = histo.sort_values('Id').ffill()
```